# How to execute commands while running this docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, docker-exec

I want to pull docker postgres image and create a database `mydb` in it. I am able to do it step by step like this

1. `docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name containername -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d postgres:12.1`
2. `docker exec -it containername /bin/bash`
3. `psql -h localhost -U postgres`
4. `CREATE database mydb;`

I wanted to add these steps in a readme documentation. Is it possible to do everything in a single command when running the container itself?
Tried something like below but couldn't succeed

`docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name terminals -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d postgres:12.1 psql -h localhost -U postgres; create database terminals`

Comment: Did you actually read the image [description and documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) (look for title "How to extend this image")? Because you can do this automatically on container startup, basically by setting some environment vars or mounting a file inside the container.

Comment: Hi, mounting a script would again make it a multi-step process.

Comment: Unless you distribute your own extended image with the scritp already there. Or you distribute the file and give insttructions ton mount it with `-v` option on the command line. Or distribute a dockerfie and the script for the guy to build his own image and lauch it. As you can see, there are numerous options.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount a init script into container:

```
docker run -d -v /local-path/your-init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/your-init.sql -p 5432:5432 --name containername -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres:12.1
```

your-init.sql:

```
CREATE database mydb;
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgres official docker images (like postgres:12.1 you are currently using) come with a [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/12/docker-entrypoint.sh) script which is able to initialize the database based on env variables ([documentation](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#how-to-extend-this-image) as also mentioned by @Zeitounator).
So, in order to start postgres and initiate the database upon startup you need to add an extra env variable (POSTGRES_DB=mydb) when you run the image:

```
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name containername -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_DB=mydb -d postgres:12.1
```